# check that requests come the web and not manual

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, request

I have a simple autocomplete script in js that takes what the user type, send it to the server and the server checks for data that resembles it. working great.

```
$(".name_autocomplete").autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '/names',
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            $(this).value = suggestion;
        }
    });
```

But since that server endpoint is public, I don't want users to abuse it and have it spit out everything  by bruteforce

Is there a way (in clientside or server side) to limit the requests for that url only from the website on that specific page and not from things like `curl`?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option would be to drop connections without a user-agent string (similarly with user agent strings that belong to known bots). Of course, if your users are clever enough to use curl, they probably know how to use a fake user agent with it (by default curl won't send a user agent string), so this will only thwart the casual busybody.

For nginx:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ (agent1|agent2) ) {
  return 444;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe HTTP-Access-control can help you in combination with a well set user-agent:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

You can control the origin domain and decide, which domain is allowed to access and which not.